# Newbie: get access privilege

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell

I am newbie on **Linux Ubuntu** machine.

I logged in to the **Ubuntu** with **username**: `student`.

There are some directories only allowed root user to access, for example `/var/lib/mysql` ,(I know I can use `sudo` to access but it is not what I want). If I want to get the access privilege on those directories with `student` account, is it so that I can run the following command :

```
chown student: PATH_TO_ROOT_USER_PRIVILEGED_DIR
```

and after that, I can access that directory by using my own account ? am I right?

- If I am right, then will **root** user lose the access privilege because I changed it to `student` user?
- If I am wrong, please tell me the right solution.

**P.S.**

please **don't** concern on what I am going to do on `/var/lib/mysql` directory, that is **only my example**, as I mentioned above, I mean **generally** **for those directories which only have root privilege**, can I use `chown` to change access privilege and will root user then loose the access because of the change made by `chown` ? I just wanna know the **effect** of `chown`.

Comment: What do you intended to do in that directory?

Comment: I think you need to look closer at `/var/lib/mysql` before you do anything.  It is almost certainly currently owned by the mysql user.  If you change permissions on that folder, you are almost certainly going to completely trash your mysql install.  There is almost no good reasons anything should have access to that folder other then the user the mysql daemon is running under.

Comment: @Mellon: Partially right. `root` can happily enter any directory and access any file, though. But if take away the ownership from any other user than root, then that regular user will lose the access to that particular directory. Regular user cannot use `chown`. There is also concept of `groups` and for more fine-grained control `Access Control Lists (ACL)`. What are you going to do in `/var/lib/mysql` anyway? Under normal circumtances all access to it should go via MySQL daemon.

Comment: @ Zoredahce and @ Janne, please see my P.S. in my post. I just want to  know the effect of using chown, which does not mean I will do some stupid thing.

Answer (score 0):

root will never lose access. Even if you change the file's owner/group.

Please never ever change the owner of `/var/lib/mysql`!

**If you change it mysql server might not be able to read/write its files anymore.**

For your access problem: you could add your user to the group root.